# Page jumps to top after dynamic data load in Firefox

Tags: jquery

I use [PrettyPhoto](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/) lightbox. My script is modified to display comments on the right side. Comments are loaded with an Ajax call (it's not an iframe).

There is a small problem in Firefox. When I click on "Load more comments", comments section jumps to top after Ajax loads data. It's strange because it happends not always. Simetimes it's jumps to top and sometimes not.

I spent a long time trying to find a solution in Google but ohe only solution it to add "cache:false". I have it but it doesn't help.

[image]

I was thinking that probably it's caused by PrettyPhoto hashtag in the URL. I tried to use the script without deeplinking but it doesn't help.

The problem is only in PrettyPhoto modal box. In a normal page the comments load without any problems.

"Jumping" problem persists only in Firefox. In Chrome, MIE everything works fine.

Below is my script to load more comments:

```
$(document.body).on('click','.morecomments',function() {
var ID = $(this).attr("id");
if(ID) {
$("#more"+ID).html('<img src="/load.gif" />');
$.ajax({
type: "POST",url: "/more.php",
data: "vid="+ ID, 
cache: false,
success: function(html){
$("#more"+ID).remove();
$("div#comments_a").append(html);
}
});
} else {
$(".morec").html('-');
}
return false;
});
```

This script loads first comments when PrettyPhoto box opens:

```
if (settings.comments=='1'){
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "/comments-load.php",
data: "cid="+actual,
cache: false,
success: function(responce){    
if(responce) {
responce2=responce;
} else {
responce2='Error loading comments';
}
document.getElementById('PutCommentOut').innerHTML=responce2;
$('.pp_next').css({'margin-right':'0px','width':'49%'});
$('#PutCommentOut').css({'width':'100%','height':'100%','overflow-x':'hidden','overflow-y':'auto','padding-bottom':'0px'});
}
});
}
```

Load more button:

```
<div id="comments_a">
    <div id="more1-5-2-0-0" class="morec"><a href="#" class="morecomments" id="1-5-2-0-0">Load more comments</a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: show HTML of `Load more comments` button please

Comment: I just edited my post and added the button.